# MBESS package in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to compute an effect size for my linear models in R with the package `MBESS`.
I installed the package and then wanted to use `effect.size (lm)` but then R tells me that it can´t find "`effect.size`".... I thought this was included in the package?

Comment: If you look(ed) [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MBESS/MBESS.pdf) you could see that the function doesn't exist in `MBESS`. Try `effsize`, `spatialEco`[page 28](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatialEco/spatialEco.pdf). I may have misspelled the names.

Comment: what is spatialEco? is it the name of the package?

Comment: Please follow the link in my comment above.

Comment: Thank you. But I can´t use Cohens d because I don´t want to compare two groups. I only got one group and I run some linear models with the data of this group. Now I want to have an effect size for this linear models.

Comment: @svenni Please edit your question to add a statement of the specific problem you have. If possible, a small code sample that shows what you are trying would also help.